# How to access a BitLocker-encrypted drive in Linux?

Tags: windows, linux, encryption, bitlocker

I have a laptop running Windows 7 Ultimate. I have encrypted my drives using BitLocker. Now I have also installed [Lubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubuntu) along with Windows. But my encrypted drives are not visible in Linux. How can I fix this?

Comment: There's a pretty detailed answer at https://askubuntu.com/a/617989/25639 too.

Answer (score 77):

You can access the BitLocker partition under Linux using [**Dislocker**](https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker/tree/develop), an open-source driver that is using FUSE (or not).

Note: You need the file on a USB key (the one with the `.bek` extension) or the recovery password.

Comment: But i don't have any USB key or recovery password. I did not setup the encryption, it came encrypted from factory settings. Where do i find the key?

Comment: @Youda008 if it still boots, run `manage-bde -protectors -get c:` to retrieve the key - at your first available opportunity.  Otherwise if it decides to stop booting one day (e.g. BIOS change), it will be unrecoverable.

Answer (score 46):

Thanks to [Aorimn](https://superuser.com/users/132622/aorimn), his [solution](https://superuser.com/a/421314/2357) worked for me. I'm fairly unexperienced with Unix, so it cost a few hours to figure it out. I thought I would describe the steps I took while my backup is running :)

My problem was that I could not boot Windows, and I needed a way to access my files on a Bitlocked partition. In order to do this, you need a bitlocker recovery password (8 groups of digits) and the ability to boot your system from USB.

1. Download and install `LiLi` on an other Windows machine ([Linux Live USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/))
2. Start `LiLi` and have it download a lightweight `ubuntu` image. I chose `Xubuntu`.
3. Install the image to your USB stick.
4. Boot the problematic machine with the USB stick
5. When you see the ubuntu boot screen, press a key.
6. Under `F6`, set the following options: `nomodeset`, `acpi=off`, `noacpi` and `nolacpi`
7. Boot `ubuntu`.
8. Make a folder `/media/windows` and `/media/mount`.
9. Download and extract [dislocker](https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker/releases)
10. `sudo apt-get install libfuse-dev libmbedtls-dev`
11. change directory to the `dislocker/src` folder
12. `sudo make`
13. `sudo make install`
14. change directory to `/usr/bin`
15. `sudo fdisk -l`
16. identify the partition which is bitlocked. Mine was `/dev/sda1`.
17. `sudo dislocker -r -V /dev/sda1 -p315442-000000-000000-000000-000000-000000-000000-000000 -- /media/windows` (replace your own bitlocker key and source partition)
18. change dir to `/media/windows` (use `sudo -i` if you can't access it)
19. `mount -o loop dislocker-file /media/mount`
20. You should now see your files in a mounted drive of the file manager.

Backups are fairly slow, but it might save some trouble if you do end up reinstalling windows. Good luck!

Comment: From the above steps I wasn't clear how `dislocker` is functioning, so here is the info, from the source "With FUSE, you have to give the program a mount point. Once keys are decrypted,
a file named `dislocker-file` appears into this provided mount point. This file
is a virtual NTFS partition, so you can mount it as any NTFS partition and then
read from it or write to it."

Comment: dislocker is now (as of Ubuntu 18.04) available in Ubuntu's repositories, so you can install it by running `sudo apt install dislocker` instead of building from source.

Comment: Is there a solution other than using dislocker? The problem is that dislocker requires compiling and (like virtually every other time I try) compiling fails.

Answer (score 19):

CryptSetup has added [**experimental**](https://man.archlinux.org/man/core/cryptsetup/cryptsetup.8.en#BITLK_(Windows_BitLocker-compatible)_EXTENSION_(EXPERIMENTAL)) support for BitLocker as of version 2.3.0 (February 2020), which is available in Ubuntu's repos for [20.10 Groovy](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cryptsetup&searchon=names&suite=groovy&section=all) onwards, although support will likely improve in later versions.

To open a BitLocker device with a password, use:

```
sudo cryptsetup open --type=bitlk <device> <name>
```

or:

```
sudo cryptsetup bitlkOpen <device> <name>
```

To open the device with a key file, use:

```
sudo cryptsetup open --type=bitlk --key-file=/etc/cryptsetup-keys.d/<name>.key <device> <name>
```

To open the device at boot time, add the following to `/etc/crypttab`:

```
<name> PARTUUID=<part_uuid> /etc/cryptsetup-keys.d/<name>.key bitlk
```

Note:

> If a keyfile is not specified, [systemd-cryptsetup(8)](https://man.archlinux.org/man/systemd-cryptsetup.8) will automatically try to load it from `/etc/cryptsetup-keys.d/name.key` and `/run/cryptsetup-keys.d/name.key` ([Source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/System_configuration#crypttab)).

So you may replace the path to the key file with `-` or `none`.

Possible parameter values:

- device - /dev/sda1
- name - windows
- part_uuid - aaaaaaaa-1111-bbbb-2222-cccccccccccc (find `PARTUUID` with `sudo blkid | grep BitLocker`)

Now you can mount the device with the following command:

```
sudo mount /dev/mapper/windows /path/to/mount/point
```

**Important note:**

When setting up BitLocker on a device choose the option that encrypts the whole device (requires more time). The other option uses Encrypt-On-Write conversion model that makes sure that **any new disk writes** are encrypted as soon as you turn on BitLocker (data that existed on the device before encryption began can still be read and written without encryption) and is not supported by Cryptsetup.

You will get the following error when you try to open the device with Encrypt-On-Write conversion model:

> BITLK devices with type 'encrypt-on-write' cannot be activated.

[Cryptsetup Manual](https://man.archlinux.org/man/core/cryptsetup/cryptsetup.8.en)

[Crypttab Manual](https://man.archlinux.org/man/crypttab.5)

[Cryptsetup 2.3.0 Release Notes](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/blob/master/docs/v2.3.0-ReleaseNotes)

[BitLocker configuration: known issues](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/bitlocker/ts-bitlocker-config-issues)

[Cryptsetup `bitlk.c`](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/blob/master/lib/bitlk/bitlk.c)

Comment: FYI The cryptsetup backend is not experimental anymore

Answer (score 8):

I just worked out a way to update Kali Linux and install `dislocker`.

Using Kali Linux 1.0.9a i386 bootable DVD

Edit "/etc/apt/sources.list" and add:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe
```

Install programs using Terminal:

```
apt-get update"
apt-get install git libfuse-dev libpolarssl-dev # Continue through update text, allow services to restart if needed
git clone git://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker.git
cd /dislocker/src
make
make install
```

Find drive Bitlocker volume:

```
fdisk -l
```

Make folders in /mnt: `tmp`, `dis`.

Run dislocker:

```
dislocker -v -V /dev/<volume name> -p<Bitlocker key> -- /mnt/tmp
```

Check if file exists to confirm proper Bitlocker key:

```
ls /mnt/tmp
```

Should return `dislocker-file` if correct.

Mount volume:

```
mount -o loop,ro /mnt/tmp/dislocker-file /mnt/dis
```

Browse to `/mnt/dis` for access to files.

Comment: `dislocker` doesn't work in Kali Linux 2.0. When I try the `make` command, following output appears:

> dislocker-fuse.c:35:19: fatal error: fuse.h: No such file or directory

And manually handling ( `apt-get install libfuse-dev` )

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  `libfuse-dev` :
> Depends: `libselinux-dev`

Comment: Great step-by-step instructions. Only thanks to this I learned that the dislocker command is not mounting itself (like `sshfs` or other things).

Answer (score 2):

BitLocker is a proprietary, closed-source drive encryption system only supported by Windows. You'll have to remove BitLocker encryption if you want to access your Windows partitions from Linux.

See *[What is the difference between disabling BitLocker Drive Encryption and decrypting the volume?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/What-is-the-difference-between-disabling-BitLocker-Drive-Encryption-and-decrypting-the-volume)* for instructions on doing so. It would be advisable to have a backup of your data completed first.

Once the drive is decrypted, you can use [TrueCrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueCrypt) instead; reading a System Encryption volume under Linux isn't supported by default, but someone has figured out a work-around. See *[How to use TrueCrypt®-encrypted Windows system drives on Linux](http://jan-krueger.net/development/truecrypt-system-drive-on-linux)*.

At the very least, review the TrueCrypt documentation and more specifically, the [list of supported OSes](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=sys-encryption-supported-os).

Yet another option is PGP Whole Disk Encryption. See [PGP Whole Disk Encryption for Dual Boot Linux and Windows XP](http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/pgp-whole-disk-encryption-dual-boot-linux-and-windows-xp).

Comment: Perhaps update for [TrueCrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueCrypt). [Steve Gibson has a page for it](https://www.grc.com/misc/truecrypt/truecrypt.htm).

Comment: @BrettDikeman You may want to adjust or delete your answer as it does not apply (or is no longer true). See https://superuser.com/a/421314/118989.

Comment: @TomaszGandor what is the update exactly? Is bitlocker not closed-source anymore? How does Dislocker actually get 'around' it?

Answer (score 2):

Please note that `libpolarssl-dev` can't be used, it has been supersede with `libmbedtls-dev`  so use this instead:

```
sudo apt-get install libmbedtls-dev
```

Note: by the way, it was a success using live boot. I am able to read and write. Just follow above steps.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, and just want to share my experience and what I learned in case it helps someone else.

I had a Bitlocker encrypted drive from Windows 10 Pro, 20H2 that was using Encrypt-On-Write. I tried everything from all the useful answers here.

TLDR; as of April 2023, **only real Bitlocker can decrypt a drive that uses Encrypt-On-Write**.

For reference, my Linux system is Mint 20.3.

I tried dislocker, building it from the latest release tag, and it couldn't decrypt with the recovery key/password.

Then I tried Cryptsetup, building from the latest source as well, it didn't work either. Thanks @denis-savran for your note about Encrypt-On-Write, that got me going in the right direction.

I tried libbde-utils, but just from the Mint 20.3 distro package.

I tried @SrjCoder's suggestion of using a VM. But with VirtualBox on the Linux host, I was not able to see the encrypted drive in the guest Windows system. The unmounted block device that had the encrypted drive was not visible in the VM. I didn't try VMware, and I'm not a VirtualBox expert, so maybe I missed something there.

Finally I installed Windows 10 Pro on a separate machine, and connected the encrypted drive, Windows recognized it as a Bitlocker drive, and I was able to unlock it with the recovery key, and the valuable data was saved! The end.

If you're wondering why I didn't just boot the encrypted drive, it is in a bad state and cannot boot. It blue-screened trying to go back to a restore point.  Luckily the data partition was still intact.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the other answers, there is a package `libbde-utils`, providing the command `bdemount`.

Usage, like:

```bash
# bdemount -p Password /dev/sda1
# bdemount -r RecoveryPassword /dev/sda1
```

see the [Ubuntu manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/bdemount.1.html)

Comment: Please provide more details otherwise your answer is in danger of getting deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If Anyone here not understanding this I have one LongCut Techinique.

1. Download [Vmware](https://www.vmware.com/in/products/workstation-pro/workstation-pro-evaluation.html) (can also install VirtualBox which is free) and [Windows 10/11 ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows10ISO) (can also install Windows 7/8)
2. Then in VMware create a new Virtual Machine with the ISO.
3. After Windows installation please connect your drive to this VM via VM tab in there.
4. Tada! Enter your BitLocker password and access the files. This Windows can also be used for testing any other things on Windows.

Comment: What do you mean by the “LongCut Techinique?”

Comment: by "LongCut", I think @SrjCoder means the opposite of a "short-cut", since this method takes a lot longer than installing dislocker or cryptsetup in Linux.

Comment: yes It is opposite to short cut

Answer (score 0):

I don't know since when `nemo` supports it, but I installed Ubuntu on a second SSD in my school laptop and could just see the `BitLocker`'d drive in the "Devices" part of `nemo`'s sidebar as "253 GB encrypted drive". When I clicked it it asked for my BitLocker key and for how long to remember it (not at all, until logout, permanent). When I entered the key it was successfully mounted as "Windows" with the path `/media/<username>/Windows`.