# Is it possible to open a drive encrypted using BitLocker Drive encryption in Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bitlocker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access bitlocker encrypted drive in linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/376533/how-to-access-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-in-linux)

While installing Ubuntu I accidentally overwrote the boot sector that loaded Windows. One of my drives was encrypted using BitLocker Drive Encryption.

Ubuntu doesn't even show that drive. Is there some way I could open that drive on Ubuntu? Or do I have to install windows again or connect that drive to a Windows pc just to get the files from the drive??

Comment: Why don't you just try and recover the boot sector?  You need to use Windows to solve this problem, Ubuntu has never been able to read a encrypted drive ( encrypted by BitLocker ) likely never will be able to.

Comment: That is a solution, thanks. I will however wait for a few more opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ramhound's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/497574/is-it-possible-to-open-a-drive-encrypted-using-bitlocker-drive-encryption-in-ubu#comment593966_497574)

> Why don't you just try and recover the boot sector? You need to use
>   Windows to solve this problem, Ubuntu has never been able to read a
>   encrypted drive ( encrypted by BitLocker ) likely never will be able
>   to.

What Ramhound told you is correct. Although there are highly technical operations using experimental software to accomplish this from GNU-Linux no reputable source that I'm aware of has published anything solid as of yet.