# accessing bitlocker volumes in redhat linux

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, bitlocker

I have a laptop running windows 7 ultimate. I have encrypted my drives using bitlocker. Now I have also installed redhat linux 6.0 along with windows. But my encrypted drives are not visible in linux. Hence I need urgent help?

Comment: other option boot back into windows transport the then unencrypted data to a linux friendly encryption solution i.e. LUKS which with some tweaking DOES work on windows too

Answer (score 0):

The only way to open BitLocker volumes directly from Linux (that I'm aware of) is `dislocker`, an open source FUSE driver for Linux and OS X. It's designed more for data recovery than for day-to-day usage; I'm not sure if it supports write at all, and it certainly can't decrypt from the TPM (because the Linux boot process is different from the Windows one, so the counter used in the TPM for BitLocker will be different) so if you use a TPM you'll need to provide the BitLocker recovery key every time you want to access the encrypted volume from Linux.

Previous question on this subject, with step-by-step:
[How to access a BitLocker-encrypted drive in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/376533/how-to-access-a-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-in-linux)

Dislocker source code: https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker

Dislocker official site: http://www.hsc.fr/ressources/outils/dislocker/