# How to decrypt hdd on Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, encryption

I need help to decrypt my HDD. It was encrypted using BitLocker on Windows 7, now I am at work I need it urgently and I only have Winvows Vista Business(x86, sp2).

And there is no bitlocker.
When I try to download it (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=24303)
It says : "The version of Windows you have installed does not match the update you are trying to install"

So, what can I do now?
I can install BitLocker to Go, but I think he can encrypt only FAT because it also give me an error message (Please insert a BitLocker-enabled drive)

Of course I know password and I have BitLocker Recovery Key.

I am asking this, because this questions dont have accepted answers,

- [How to access a BitLocker-encrypted drive in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/376533/how-to-access-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-in-linux)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/187329/can-i-decrypt-a-partition-in-ubuntu-which-is-encrypted-using-bitlocker-utility
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/199219/i-secured-my-usb-using-bitlocker-on-a-windows-7-pc-but-now-i-cant-see-it-in-ubun

Have any one try to use

- http://www.hsc.fr/ressources/outils/dislocker/download/
- http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/

Or any other similar software?

Comment: I'm not sure but wasn't bitlocker offered only for ultimate (enterprise) versions of vista?

Comment: And the ultimate and enterprise versions of Win 7 too!  I have win7 pro and it does not have bitlocker.

Comment: @mdpc - Every version of Windows 7 could read a Bitlocker protected.Only certain versions could encrypt the drives.  **'If you’re running Windows 7 and want to encrypt drives in BitLocker, you must have the Windows 7 Enterprise edition or Windows 7 Ultimate edition. However, you can open and modify encrypted drives in any edition of Windows 7."**

Comment: The solution is simple.  You can either upgrade the Vista license to Enterprise or Ultimate although your choices are limited because you have the Business edition or you can upgrade the machine to version of Windows 7 with an upgrade path from Windows Vista Business.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I need help to decrypt my HDD.

> It was encrypted using BitLocker on Windows 7, now I am at work I need it urgently and I only have Windows Vista Business(x86, sp2).

If you have a removable drive formatted as **FAT, FAT32, or exFAT** you may be able to use **BitLocker To Go**, which can be downloaded from [BitLocker To Go Reader](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24303)

In addition, as per comment by [ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound):

- All versions of Windows after Windows 7 have the capability to read a
  Bitlocker protected device.
- The FAT limitation of Bitlocker to Go was also removed as the
  program itself became a feature of Windows.

---

#### BitLocker Drive Encryption Overview

> **What happens if I try to open a BitLocker-protected, NTFS-formatted removable drive by using a computer running Windows XP or Windows
>   Vista?**
>
> In most cases, Windows XP and Windows Vista will not be able to
>   recognize a BitLocker-protected, NTFS-formatted removable drive. In
>   many situations, the user will be prompted to format the drive.
>   Because of this, it is recommended that removable drives be formatted
>   by using the FAT, FAT32, or exFAT file system when using BitLocker.
>
> **What is BitLocker To Go?**
>
> BitLocker To Go is BitLocker Drive Encryption on removable data
>   drives. This includes the encryption of USB flash drives, SD cards,
>   external hard disk drives, and other drives formatted by using the
>   NTFS, FAT16, FAT32, or exFAT file systems.
>
> **Can I save files to my BitLocker-protected removable drive when I am using Windows XP or Windows Vista?**
>
> No. The BitLocker To Go Reader provides read-only access to
>   BitLocker-protected removable drives.
>
> **Can I download a copy of the BitLocker To Go Reader?**
>
> Yes. To download the BitLocker To Go Reader, see Microsoft Download
>   Center: BitLocker To Go Reader.
>
> **Why am I unable to access my removable drive on computers running Windows XP or Windows Vista when using the BitLocker To Go Reader?**
>
> The most common reason for this situation is that the drive is not
>   formatted by using the FAT, FAT32, or exFAT file systems. To check for
>   this, insert the drive in a computer running Windows 7 or later,
>   right-click the drive, and then click Properties to see the file
>   format of the drive. Another reason could be that the system
>   administrator has disabled access to removable drives from previous
>   versions of Windows by using the BitLocker Group Policy settings. To
>   check for this, attempt to access the drive from a computer running
>   Windows XP or Windows Vista that is not joined to the domain.

Source [BitLocker Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/bitlocker-drive-encryption-overview)

Comment: It might be a worth while addition to this answer to indicate that all versions of `Windows` after `Windows 7` have the capability to read a Bitlocker protected device.  Additionally the FAT limitation of `Bitlocker to Go` was also removed, since the program itself, became a feature of Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound thx, answer updated

Comment: @DavidPostill thanx for answer but at the momment I cant accept your answer, because It explains that I cant do it. No I will try to use some other software and If I cant decrypt I will accept it as it cant be done

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid that you'll probably be forced to go to those backups that you should be keeping.

The purpose of disk encryption is afterall NOT to be able to do what you are suggestion.  Otherwise, why use this to keep your disk secure?

Comment: The purpose of disk encryption is to decrypt it with password. No metter of OS I am using!

Comment: Oh not true....disk encryption methods vary in scope and ability to decrypt by OS or application for a variety of reasons.  I'm afraid you'd be hard pressed to decrypt a BitLocker disk on Linux....also try to decrypt a Linux based encrypted filesystem system on a Windows box.  Also encryption/decryption using an application is NOT OS general and again restricted to the specific application.

Comment: Ok you are right I wasn't aware of that. (I google it because I can run ubuntu from USB, but so far I didn't found appropriate support for bitlocker)

Comment: @malakrsnaslava  - You used a encryption method that isn't supported on every operating system.  **Your argument is invalid.**

Comment: so why the downvote here?  I think my answer is in keeping in line with what you are going to have to do.

Comment: When you have the recovery password you can decrypt bitlocker partitions.

Comment: @bobes, yes on Windows assumming you remember to save this somewhere (or in the enterprise case asking your systems administrator).

Comment: @mdpc - Honestly.  Because its more of a comment.