# How to open a encrypted hard drive on linux?

Tags: linux, windows, bitlocker

Hey I have encrypted my hard drive using Bitlocker in windows.
How to open my hard drive on Linux and How to remove password ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can't (but I don't know Windows and I don't know Bitlocker).

You could (and generally should) have separate [disk partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning) for Linux, and set up Linux to encrypt some (Linux dedicated) partition (see also [dm-crypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dm-crypt)). You'll better have three partitions for Linux: a root partition (about 60Gbytes) for the Linux system, a swap partition (perhaps 16Gbytes), and a home partition for your Linux user data (i.e. `/home`). That home partition can be an encrypted Linux file system (and many recent distributions propose you such a setup at initialization, i.e. Linux installation, time). See also [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212556/50557).

Answer (score 0):

BitLocker is a proprietary encryption mechanism created by Microsoft. As a result, if your non-Microsoft OS (I.e. Linux) cannot decrypt BitLocker encryption you cannot access the drive or partition (whichever is encrypted).

A small number of projects for Linux may offer **some** support but there's no guarantee: [enter link description here](https://superuser.com/questions/376533/how-to-access-a-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-in-linux)