# How to access BitLocker encrypted drive with Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: bash, bitlocker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I can see the mounted container in `/mnt/w/` but cannot access any contents there.

Comment: [How to access a BitLocker-encrypted drive in Linux?](http://superuser.com/questions/376533/how-to-access-a-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-in-linux).  Skip the irrelevant parts of the instructions submitted by Jodiug.  Accessing Bitlocker volumes on Windows Subsystem for Linux, is not a supported featre at this time but it should be possible.  You just have to provide a driver for it (i.e. Dislocker).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a BitLocker-encrypted drive in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/376533/how-to-access-a-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-in-linux)

Comment: If you don't mind rebooting the WSL, https://superuser.com/a/1347725/29248 seems to work in the scenario where WSL is started after BL protection was removed

Answer (score 9):

After unlocking the bitlocker volume/partition on Windows, execute on WSL:

```
sudo mount -t drvfs -o uid=1000,gid=1000 W: /mnt/w
```

Answer (score 2):

What works for me, is unlocking the bitlocker volume in Windows before starting the Ubuntu bash (WSL). If I start the WSL bash before unlocking, I won't see anything until rebooting Windows and then unlocking the volume before launching the WSL bash.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.