# How to enable SSD's self-encryption on HP EliteBook 840 G8?

Tags: windows, ssd, bitlocker, self-encrypting-drive, hp-drive-lock

We bought new HP EliteBook 840 G8 laptops with SSDs running Windows 11 and wanted to enable their self encryption with password or fingerprint authentication at boot-up, but without the need for additional tools. Since I couldn't find any suitable guide on the Internet, I thought I'm gonna summarize the instructions here since the set up is a bit weird with HP laptops — at least, in comparison to other vendors like Lenovo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Preliminary considerations

HP offers two different options: DriveLock and Automatic DriveLock. While DriveLock is best for single-user devices, Automatic DriveLock was designed for multi-user devices. **Please note that these two alternatives are not only mutually exclusive, but also cannot be switched once one of them has be set up** — at least, switching from one to the other didn't work on our laptops!

## Setting up SSD encryption on HP EliteBook 840 G8

1. Activate BitLocker on Windows — it was enabled, but not activated. (Even [HP Support](https://support.hp.com/th-en/document/c01674996) missed this crucial step.) **Make sure to backup the recovery key!**
2. Reboot and enter UEFI/BIOS by pressing ESC repeatedly and then F10.
3. Go to "Security" → "Hard Drive Utilities" → "DriveLock/Automatic Drive Lock".
4. Select you SSD.
5. Select "Enable DriveLock" and set a administrator password. **Caution: Backup this password!** *The administrator password is required to disable DriveLock again.*
6. Set a user password. *The user password is required to unlock the drive at boot time.*
7. Save and exit UEFI/BIOS.
8. Now you will be prompted for the BitLocker recovery key (see step 1). Confirm it by pressing enter.

Comment: How is this HP encryption, if it uses Microsoft BitLocker? And can it be used under Linux? See https://superuser.com/questions/376533/how-to-access-a-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-in-linux